# How cassandra interpreter work?

Tags: cassandra, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I have installed **zeppelin** on my local machine, it work correctly but I can't use **cassandra interpreter**
when I tap in notebook,

```
%cassandra
HELP;
```

then I run, an error display
Please, someone can help me?

Comment: What exactly error do you get?

Comment: What is the error? Is Cassandra running?